# Handling migrations to coredata in a framework using app groups?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have a Cocoa Touch Framework in which I have all my of my models and other coredata stack related objects. The stack initializes the sqlite file to a location in a shared app group. Multiple apps are going to share these models and persisted storage (hence the need to put the models in a framework and use shared app group to store the sqlite file).

This works fine, sharing data between the 2 apps, until an update to the framework causing a migration to the coredata related entities is needed as I can't guarantee both apps will get updated on the device with new version of the framework at the same time. The code for both apps is still valid and still runs fine (App A with Framework V1, App B with Framework V2), but the sqlite database will become modified from the migration from App B's update.

Is it possible to have this work with coredata? I can get it to work with sqlite using FMDB or similar (as long as DB schema updates are purely additive) but would like the conveniences of coredata. The problem with coredata can be illustrated following these steps:

- App A is installed with Framework V1 & run, coredata creates DB in app group
- App B is installed with Framework V1 & run, doesn't need to create db, just uses it from app group
- App B is updated with Framework V2 & run, migration on DB to add columns/rename columns, all is well
- App A is run again (still with Framework V1), undoes what App B just did (removes added columns, deletes data from columns that were renamed & renames back)
- As both apps go back and forth being run, DB schema keeps going back and forth (due to migrations I think??) & data is lost

Is what I am trying to do possible with coredata or should I go forward with FMDB or similar?

With FMDB I get to manually control the DB (create/alter tables) and cast into my models so I can add/leave out columns when converting to my models so that the same data source can be used for both.

Some code below to help (this works assuming the all apps are running same version of framework):

```
let groupID = "group.com.company.sharedgroup"
let bundleID = "com.company.framework"
let modelName = "Model"

lazy var diskStoreDescription: NSPersistentStoreDescription = {
    let groupContainer = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: groupID)!
    let sqliteURL = groupContainer.appendingPathComponent(modelName).appendingPathExtension("sqlite")
    return NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: sqliteURL)
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    let bundle = Bundle(identifier: bundleID)!
    let momdURL = bundle.url(forResource: modelName, withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: momdURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: modelName, managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel)
    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [diskStoreDescription]
    container.loadPersistentStores {}
    return container
}()
```

Core data does magic and makes table `ZOBJECT` with columns `Z_PK`, `Z_ENT`, `Z_OPT`, `ZNAME`

```
//Model V1
class Object: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var name: String
}
```

Core data does magic and updates table `ZOBJECT` with columns `ZTITLE`

```
//Model V2
class Object: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var title: String?
}
```

Running App A (with Model V1) after App B (with Model V2) removes the `ZTITLE` column but doesn't throw exceptions or errors. Then re-running App B (with Model V2) re-creates `ZTITLE`. I would like App A to continue functioning normally and just ignore `ZTITLE`. Answers could range from `this is how you should do this...` to `coredata is not meant to support this, use FMDB`. Thanks!

Comment: Ended up using [GRDB](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift) to accomplish this goal